# Django-bleach import and deploy to heroku error

Tags: python, django, heroku

I am using Django 1.11.

I'm using in my Django application the django-bleach that was installed with:

```
pip install django-bleach
```

Here the lib folder when django-bleach is installed this way:

```
drwxr-xr-x  3 breno breno 4,0K jan  7 18:30 bleach
drwxr-xr-x  2 breno breno 4,0K jan  7 18:30 bleach-2.1.2.dist-info
drwxr-xr-x 19 breno breno 4,0K jan  7 18:30 django
drwxr-xr-x  2 breno breno 4,0K jan  7 18:30 Django-2.0.1.dist-info
drwxr-xr-x  4 breno breno 4,0K jan  7 18:30 django_bleach
drwxr-xr-x  2 breno breno 4,0K jan  7 18:30 django_bleach-0.3.0.egg-info
-rw-r--r--  1 breno breno  126 jan  7 18:18 easy_install.py
drwxr-xr-x  8 breno breno 4,0K jan  7 18:30 html5lib
drwxr-xr-x  2 breno breno 4,0K jan  7 18:30 html5lib-1.0.1.dist-info
drwxr-xr-x 11 breno breno 4,0K jan  7 18:18 pip
drwxr-xr-x  2 breno breno 4,0K jan  7 18:18 pip-9.0.1.dist-info
drwxr-xr-x  5 breno breno 4,0K jan  7 18:18 pkg_resources
drwxr-xr-x  2 breno breno 4,0K jan  7 18:18 pkg_resources-0.0.0.dist-info
drwxr-xr-x  2 breno breno 4,0K jan  7 18:30 __pycache__
drwxr-xr-x  4 breno breno 4,0K jan  7 18:30 pytz
drwxr-xr-x  2 breno breno 4,0K jan  7 18:30 pytz-2017.3.dist-info
drwxr-xr-x  5 breno breno 4,0K jan  7 18:18 setuptools
drwxr-xr-x  2 breno breno 4,0K jan  7 18:18 setuptools-32.3.1.dist-info
drwxr-xr-x  2 breno breno 4,0K jan  7 18:30 six-1.11.0.dist-info
-rw-r--r--  1 breno breno  31K jan  7 18:30 six.py
drwxr-xr-x  3 breno breno 4,0K jan  7 18:30 webencodings
drwxr-xr-x  2 breno breno 4,0K jan  7 18:30 webencodings-0.5.1.dist-info
```

So, when I would use it, I've gotten an import error that I fixed, the error occurs in Django version 1.6 or 1.8+, I guess. You can see [here](https://bitbucket.org/breno_asrm/django-bleach/commits/82ab7e4bc9cb87824170d25d98c1880a44a9e764) what I did. It worked and I continue the development.

The problem is: now I am trying to deploy my application in Heroku, but the same error occurs and the import has to be fixed.

So, I think that my repository should have the requirements.txt with the correct version of django-bleach (the one that have my commit), this way it would works properly, right?

So, I forked the repository, commited the modification and created a requirements.txt with this text:

```
-e git+https://breno_asrm@bitbucket.org/breno_asrm/django-bleach.git#egg=django-bleach
```

Then I created a new virtual env and installed with

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Here is the result of the lib folder of this environment

```
drwxr-xr-x  3 breno breno 4,0K jan  7 18:15 bleach
drwxr-xr-x  2 breno breno 4,0K jan  7 18:15 bleach-2.1.2.dist-info
drwxr-xr-x 19 breno breno 4,0K jan  7 18:15 django
drwxr-xr-x  2 breno breno 4,0K jan  7 18:15 Django-2.0.1.dist-info
-rw-r--r--  1 breno breno   51 jan  7 18:15 django-bleach.egg-link
-rw-r--r--  1 breno breno   50 jan  7 18:15 easy-install.pth
-rw-r--r--  1 breno breno  126 jan  7 18:14 easy_install.py
drwxr-xr-x  8 breno breno 4,0K jan  7 18:15 html5lib
drwxr-xr-x  2 breno breno 4,0K jan  7 18:15 html5lib-1.0.1.dist-info
drwxr-xr-x 11 breno breno 4,0K jan  7 18:14 pip
drwxr-xr-x  2 breno breno 4,0K jan  7 18:14 pip-9.0.1.dist-info
drwxr-xr-x  5 breno breno 4,0K jan  7 18:14 pkg_resources
drwxr-xr-x  2 breno breno 4,0K jan  7 18:14 pkg_resources-0.0.0.dist-info
drwxr-xr-x  2 breno breno 4,0K jan  7 18:15 __pycache__
drwxr-xr-x  4 breno breno 4,0K jan  7 18:15 pytz
drwxr-xr-x  2 breno breno 4,0K jan  7 18:15 pytz-2017.3.dist-info
drwxr-xr-x  5 breno breno 4,0K jan  7 18:14 setuptools
drwxr-xr-x  2 breno breno 4,0K jan  7 18:14 setuptools-32.3.1.dist-info
drwxr-xr-x  2 breno breno 4,0K jan  7 18:15 six-1.11.0.dist-info
-rw-r--r--  1 breno breno  31K jan  7 18:15 six.py
drwxr-xr-x  3 breno breno 4,0K jan  7 18:15 webencodings
drwxr-xr-x  2 breno breno 4,0K jan  7 18:15 webencodings-0.5.1.dist-info
```

I thought it would install the same thing as before, just adding my modification, but it was not what happened.

For instance, now my lib directory (env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/
) doesn't have django_bleach folder.

So, how could I fix it in a way that I don't have to modify the heroku virtualenv that is created automatically (if it's possible)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like pip is unable to authenticate with your user `breno_asrm`. As the repository is public - just remove your username in front.

```
-e git+https://bitbucket.org/breno_asrm/django-bleach.git#egg=django-bleach
```

**Where do the files go?**

Dependencies installed by pip using `-e` from a repository are located in another folder of your environment.

From the man page of pip:

> -e,--editable
>
> Install a project in editable mode (i.e.  setuptools "develop  mode")  from  a  local project path or a VCS url.

Have a look in `venv_root/src` - you'll see django-bleach there (which in your case is a clone of your git repository). `venv_root/lib/python3.x/sites-packages/django-bleach.egg-link` includes the information where the sources can be found. Check it using `less` or `cat`. In my case it looks like this:

```
/tmp/env/src/django-bleach
.%
```

The environment will work as expected.

Together with the following option of pip all this makes more sense. This way you can easily work on an library while it is installed but not necessarily located in your environment.

> --src < dir >
>
> Directory to check out editable projects into.  The default in a virtualenv is "< venvpath >/src".  The default for global installs is "< current dir >/src".

Comment: I tried this way too, same error. Django, htmlib and other dependences is installed just fine but as I said, there is no django_bleach folder in the lib directory as when it is installed via pip install django-bleach. I will update my question listing the lib folder

Comment: I've updated my answer with an explanation of where the files can be found.